# Sharing a symlinked (`mklink /d`) directory via SMB?

Tags: windows, server-message-block, symbolic-link

I have a Windows 7 amd64 box where one directory is shared:

- local path is `d:\drop\`
- remote path is `\\aloism\drop`
- from SMB point of view, `Everyone` has Read and Write permission
- ACLs for the folder are set so that all authenticated users have read and write permissions:
  `NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(OI)(CI)C` (which is inherited to all levels below)

Now I create a symbolic link within the structure of the directory:

```
D:\drop>mklink /d tools2 tools
symbolic link created for tools2 <<===>> tools
```

The problem is that I can't access this new directory from any of the remote machines (a Windows 7 box and a Windows XP box—both behave the same way):

```
C:\>dir  \\aloism\drop\tools2\
Volume in drive \\aloism\drop is droot
Volume Serial Number is FA73-1897

Directory of \\aloism\drop\tools2

File Not Found
```

How can I make it work? Possibly also for files?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should use [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_File_System_%28Microsoft%29) for this kind of mappings. Another alternative would be [NTFS junction point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point)

Comment: I have changed these links to `junction`s and actually I do get to access the folder.

Comment: On the other hand, DFS is not really relevant for desktop, although it *is* inplace here. So I suggest splitting the answer into two Answers so I can +1 the other one as well .-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm by no means a pro but I solved a very similar situation by mapping the drive then sharing this new Z: on the Network.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/map-a-network-drive-in-windows-7-f5529cc1-5d09-89e5-c666-11e5d96229b0